# How to change the default 'material table' icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

How can I change the default icons of the material table? I do not want to use the material-icons package as described it the material-table package. Any idea?

I would like to use the 'zmdi' font instead of default icons. This is what i did already just want to know what I am doing is right?

Thanks in advance.

```
const tableIcons: Icons = {
Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <span className="zmdi zmdi-search"/>),
Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <span className="zmdi zmdi-search"/>)
```

};

```
<MaterialTable
    icons={tableIcons}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const tableIcons: Icons = {
Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <span className="zmdi zmdi-search" />),
Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div {...props} ref={ref}>
    <span className="zmdi zmdi-close" />
  </div>
)),
SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div {...props} ref={ref}>
    <span className="zmdi zmdi-long-arrow-up" />
  </div>
)),
FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div {...props} ref={ref}>
    <span className="zmdi zmdi-caret-left" />
  </div>
)),
NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div {...props} ref={ref}>
    <span className="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right" />
  </div>
)),
PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div {...props} ref={ref}>
    <span className="zmdi zmdi-chevron-left" />
  </div>
)),
LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div {...props} ref={ref}>
    <span className="zmdi zmdi-caret-right" />
  </div>
)),
ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div {...props} ref={ref}>
    <span className="zmdi zmdi-close" />
  </div>
)),
ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div {...props} ref={ref}>
    <span className="zmdi zmdi-close" />
  </div>
))
```

};

Well I managed to do this like this.